# Can i use APK of one android app in another?

Tags: android, apk, publish

I already have a published app. I want to create a new version of the same app with new features. My questions is that can i make a new project for the same app and use old project's APK in the new one so when we publish it, it would be published as a vew version of the same application?

Comment: Hello, @fakhra! Welcome to Stackoverflow!
Do you have a source code of this app?

Comment: Yes you can. The package name of the updated APK or app bundle needs to be the same as the current version. Learn more: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en

Comment: what about iOS? is it possible for iOS too?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement module but not apk as of my think its better add modules in your project

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the old APK. You can just create a new project with the same package name and use the same signing key, and use the resulting APK as a new version.

Comment: what about the same case in iOS? is it possible?

Comment: I don't know about iOS, but I strongly think so; it would be pretty stupid not being able to do a complete rewrite of an app; and even if, what purpose would the old app package serve, since it isn't used anyways? Since you can always modify parts of an app, what part of an app would have to stay the same? On Android, that's just the package name + sign key that need to stay the same. On iOS, it's probably similar.